# Two TabBar Views, modally switch between them Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have two tabbar view controllers and I like the look and feel of switching between them with a horizontal modal presentation.  My question is, if I use Xcode's simple control and drag to select a modal transition, is it simply adding more tab bar controllers to the stack?  Because I notice when I dismiss views to try and 'logout' it makes me click a few extra times if I've flipped back and forth between my tab bar views.

Should I be self.dismiss-ing them and then using the completion handler to modally present the next tab bar controller?  Cause I can't seem to get that to work either.

Or perhaps I should embed the initial view in a Navigation Controller and just hide the nav bar unless needed for logout?

Here's a screenshot for clarity.
[image: overview of two tab bar controllers in xcode]

Comment: I'm not super familiar with storyboard navigation, but I would consider embedding both `TabBarControllers` in a `NavigationController` to navigate between them - using `push`/`pop`, not `present`. (When you `present` a fresh instance of a view controller without dismissing the previous, you are adding more to the stack.) I can walk you through that programatically, if you're interested!

Comment: When you push or pop, can you use the horizontal animation?

Comment: Yep. By default, pushing goes to right, popping goes to left. Popping will deallocate the second `TabBarController` you push to - unless there's a retained reference.

Comment: Oh, okay.  Cool thank you.  I was looking for the horizontal flip animation.  I guess I'm just being picky. Lol.